# Remove all images using Ansible module

Tags: docker, ansible

I know how remove all images using shell:

```yaml
- shell: |
      docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
      docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
      docker rmi $(docker images -q)
      exit 0
```

Also I can remove image with `docker_image` by name:

```yaml
- name: Remove image
  docker_image:
    state: absent
    name: {{image_name}}
```

But, is there a way to remove **all** images using `docker_image` module or any other Ansible module for working with docker?

Comment: Note that: `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q); docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` can be reduced to `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to do it in multiple steps, like your sub-shells are doing it:

1. list docker objects, including images and containers, with the module [`docker_host_info`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_host_info_module.html#ansible-collections-community-docker-docker-host-info-module)
2. remove all those containers, with the module [`docker_container`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_container_module.html#ansible-collections-community-docker-docker-container-module)
3. remove all those images, with the module [`docker_image module`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_image_module.html#ansible-collections-community-docker-docker-image-module)

So, in Ansible:

```yaml
- docker_host_info:
    images: yes
    containers: yes
  register: docker_objects

- docker_container:
    name: "{{ item.Id }}"
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ docker_objects.containers }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.Id }}"

- docker_image:
    name: item.RepoTags | first
    state: absent
    force_absent: yes
  loop: "{{ docker_objects.images }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.RepoTags | first }}"
```